# Python-gst -> List All Properties of an Element

Tags: gstreamer, python-gstreamer, pygst

If it possbile to recive all element properties that a Element has?
I can list the elements but I dont know (also after reading docs)
how I can access the properties.

```
from gi.repository import Gst
Gst.init()
reg = Gst.Registry.get()

for x in reg.get_plugin_list():
     print x.get_name(), x.get_version()
```

The goal is to convert the properties and the element information into a json format like:

```
{
    "name": <plugin-name>,
    "version": <plugin-version>
    "properties": {
        "<property-key>": {
            "desc": <propertie-desc>,
            "value": <propertie-value>,
            "data-type": <propertie-type>,
         }
     }
}
```

Thank you Guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function you're looking for is [g_object_class_list_properties()](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-The-Base-Object-Type.html#g-object-class-list-properties) which will give you list of properties supported by each element. e.g.

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0')
from gi.repository import Gst, GObject
Gst.init([])
e = Gst.ElementFactory.make("identity", None)
e.list_properties()
[<GParamString 'name'>, <GParamObject 'parent'>, <GParamBoolean 'qos'>, <GParamUInt 'sleep-time'>, <GParamInt 'error-after'>, <GParamFloat 'drop-probability'>, <GParamFlags 'drop-buffer-flags'>, <GParamInt 'datarate'>, <GParamBoolean 'silent'>, <GParamBoolean 'single-segment'>, <GParamString 'last-message'>, <GParamBoolean 'dump'>, <GParamBoolean 'sync'>, <GParamInt64 'ts-offset'>, <GParamBoolean 'check-imperfect-timestamp'>, <GParamBoolean 'check-imperfect-offset'>, <GParamBoolean 'signal-handoffs'>]
```

---

This is also what `gst-inspect-1.0` does as well. See [the code](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gstreamer/tree/tools/gst-inspect.c#n282).

Comment: perfect thank you, it is also possible to get an list of the possible signals that an element have, I have seen that in the source code there is a function "print_signal_info " but I dont can find a similar function on python, do you have a tipp for me =)

Comment: Some clever use of `g_signal_list_ids()` and `g_signal_query()` will probably get you what you want.